# How can I make these processing.js functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry, khan-academy

In this tutorial: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-games-visualizations/programming-3d-shapes/a/rotating-3d-shapes it shows how to make 3d shapes and rotating them. I followed the steps by re-creating everything in javascript instead of processing.js but could not for some reason do these functions (in javascript):

```
var rotateY3D = function(theta) {
   var sinTheta = sin(theta);
   var cosTheta = cos(theta);
   for (var n = 0; n < nodes.length; n++) {
      var node = nodes[n];
      var x = node[0];
      var z = node[2];
      node[0] = x * cosTheta - z * sinTheta;
      node[2] = z * cosTheta + x * sinTheta;
   }
};
```

This is was my attempt:

```
var rotateZ3D = function (theta) {
        var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
        var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);
        for (var n = 0; n<nodes.length; n++) {

            var x = nodes[n][0];
            var y = nodes[n][1];
            nodes[n][0] = x * cosTheta - y * sinTheta;
            nodes[n][1] = y * cosTheta + x * sinTheta;
        }
 }
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong or if I have to go about it completaly differentaly?

Comment: Looks like khan-academy is using  `sin` and `cos` implementations that receive degrees as parameters, `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` receive radians. Guess you are getting some wacky results =)

Comment: Ohh is it the theta parameter that always changes when I am dragging with my mouse?

Comment: `mouseDragged = function() { rotateY3D(mouseX - pmouseX); rotateX3D(mouseY - pmouseY); };` it is the "size" of mouse movement. Also notice that the original value is changed and lost.

Comment: But is there a way to make this work with radians? Or have degress turn into very specific radian values?

Comment: Sure. Usually I will say you to google it but I just had lunch... `var theta_in_rads = theta * Math.PI / 180;` or define functions for that (I guess processing.js does this) `function sin_of_degeers(degs) { return Math.sin(degs * Math.PI / 180); }`.

Comment: I replaced the suggested source error with this:

var rotateZ3D = function (theta) {
  var theta_in_rads = theta * Math.PI / 180;
  var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta_in_rads);
  var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta_in_rads);
  for (var n = 0; n<nodes.length; n++) {
   
   var x = nodes[n][0];
   var y = nodes[n][1];
   nodes[n][0] = x * cosTheta - y * sinTheta;
   nodes[n][1] = y * cosTheta + x * sinTheta;
  }
 }

Comment: Sill dosen't work though.

Comment: What error it gives?

Comment: Nothing in the console. My square which I have created dosen't rotate at all.

Comment: That function is ok. Could you talk about "where are you coding"? Maybe create a fiddle (show surrounding code, or something).

Comment: I am coding in sumblime text 3. I can't use JSfiddle since I am drawing on the canvas which is an html feature. I pasted all my code in pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/TP8rsxzC though it dosen't display the result of the code like JSfiddle :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem initially was with the use of the "sin" and "cos" functions.
Your `theta` was in degrees and the javascript's built-in ones use radians.

(If needed the conversion details can be found in the question comments)

After fixing that the problem was with the surrounding code.

(Here is a fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/bvqswvnL/1/)

First to see any results of the rotation you should call the `draw` function AFTER the `rotateZ3D` one.

To show the result (and the function working) I added a `setInterval` so the point are continually **rotated** and **draw**.

Also:

- Added a `board.restore();` to the end of the `draw` function so the transformations don't "pile up";
- Changed `board.lineTo(node1[1], node1[1])` to `board.lineTo(node1[0], node1[1])` (guess this was the actual intent;

(Here is a fiddle with the result http://jsfiddle.net/bvqswvnL/2/)

Comment: It worked and I am very grateful; but I stumbled upon a big problem. Now that I moved on to the next step (3d shape generating cuboids functions instead of having fixed draw values for the nodes, edges etc.) but my code totally outputs a crazy looking shape. Here is the new code: http://pastebin.com/T23HYGMP
I created a createCuboid function which replaced the nodes and edges arrays (and its values) with the parameter data which instigates being able to create cuboids however you like but it outputs something crazy. Thanks for the help before!

Comment: The problem is with your `createCuboid` function. You have the "nodes" ok, but are creating the edges wrong.

Comment: I fixed it by connecting the edges to different nodes but why do I have do this? If it worked with the first one when connecting those nodes to eachother why didn't this one? I changed the edges arrays from what I had on the pastebin to this:[0, 1],[3,5],[3, 0],[2, 0],[4, 7],[5, 7],[7, 6],[2, 4],[1, 4],[1, 5],[2, 6],[3, 6]

Comment: That with why you changed the node definition order... By "the nodes are ok" read they cover all necessary nodes but are not in the same order the hard coded (and now commented) values are.

Comment: The nodes in question are node3 and node4.